# LaTeX3 macro identification in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, expl3, syntax-highlighting

The LaTeX3 syntax is not recognized by TeXstudio, and I'm looking for ways to solve it.

The problem comes from (IMHO) the underscores being taken as "separators"...

Here is an example:

[image: TeXstudio output]

The macro is `\__test_choose_value` and should be highlighted accordingly, the same for `\str_case`, and the others

How can I make TeXstudio understands `_` as regular string and not a special char?

By analyzing it, a LaTeX3 macro starts with `\` and end before `:`. Any ideas how to implement that in the syntax processor of TeXstudio?

Comment: Just a note: The `:` and the parameter specifation are also part of the macro. So `\str_case:nnF` is one macro name.

Comment: Related: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1178/, https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/61

Comment: On a separate note, `\ExplSyntaxOn` should be a recognized command unless you've unchecked `latex-document.cwl` in the menu, or your version of TeXstudio is old.

Comment: Just a note: Had the same problem. But there seems to be no solution, since the GitHub issue is still *open*. Recently switched to **VS Code** resp. **VSCodium** with `Latex Workshop` extension and made `LaTeX-Expl3` the standard language for `.tex`, `.cls`,  `.sty` files etc. Syntax highlighting works really well and it has a extensive command preview/suggestion for `expl3` too. So, goodbye **TexStudio**...

Comment: Been usign VScode only for python and bash, I guess it's goodbye to TeXstudio as well ^^

Comment: @lukeflo Maybe you could write a short answer mentioning vscode/vscodium as an alternative? This questions comes up every now and then and if it had answer we could close all the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Following @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz request I post an partial answer. Of course, this will not answer the initial question if and how Latex3 macros can be highlighted within Texstudio.

I would suggest switching to an editor/IDE which supports Latex3 highlighting. VSCode/Codium has really good support for Latex3 macros using the Latex Workshop extension. Thus, it was my first suggestion in the comments and is a very good solution.

But, personally, I wasn't very pleased with VSCodium due to different reasons. As a result I switched to Emacs and am very happy with it. The Latex package AUCTeX doesn't support Latex3 highlighting either, but of course Emacs is highly customisable. Thus, with support from some other users, I managed my own syntax highlighting for Latex3: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698189/297560

The last approach is, of course, just a personal preference. VSCode should be a good solution for most Latex users who want advanced Latex3 support; indeed, just regarding that issue, I don't know a better syntax highlighting and auto completion system than that used by Latex Workshop.

Comment: Thank you for this nice overview!

Answer (score 2):

TeXstudio now offers some basic syntax highlighting for expl3 code, see this commit: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/commit/f14060826c6fa2847761fd3e3ff9e7cfa81f9841

I assume that this new feature will be included in TeXstudio 4.7.4 onward.

Compiling the [current dev. version](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/commits/master/) from github will highlight your code like this:

[image]