# Looking for a good Emacs/AUCTeX setup for LaTeX3

Tags: latex3, emacs, auctex, auto-completion, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to switch my editor from vscodium (telemetry free VS Code) to Emacs. So far, I've installed AUCTeX and tried some things in a testdocument. For regular LaTeX code everything is fine.

But for LaTeX3 code I couldn't figure out a satisfying solution so far. By default there seems to be whether proper syntax highlighting support, nor a running auto-completion mechanism for LaTeX3 code. It is possible to parse packages `expl3` and `xparse` with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> in a document or automate this with `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` in the `.emacs` init file. But to accomplish it, I've to load the packages with `\usepackage` or `\RequirePackage` before parsing. That seems very unnecessary since those macros are part of the kernel for some time.

Besides that, it works good for `xparse` command with a recognisable syntax and auto-completion. For LaTeX3 commands the result is not very pleasant regarding syntax highlighting (all in dim gray), and an auto-completion mechanism is totally missing (even with `auto-completion-auctex` package). As far as I have searched, there are not too many posts regarding that topic, whether on TeX.SE, nor anywhere else in the web. [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384231/expl3-syntax-highlight-in-emacs/384335#comment1689193_384335) e.g. suggests in an up-to-date comment similar cluelessness (I also tried the possiblities suggested in other comments/linked posts of the same question). Searching for `auctex`/`emacs` in combination with `expl3`/`latex3` on our site also offers very few answers: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=auctex+expl3), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=emacs+expl3), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=emacs+latex3), [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=auctex+latex3).

**Therefore, my question is**: I know here are some longstanding (La)TeX vets who use emacs since decades. What setup are you using when working with LaTeX3 code? Is there a solution I've missed (which is a true possibility), do you edited/created needed lisp code yourself or do you just don't quarrel that much with code highlighting etc.

---

**Edit**: @AndrewStacey offers a good working solution in [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129521/297560) linked to from the post I mentioned earlier. It produces good syntax highlighting in many cases. There are some things I might change, as that commands beginning with `\str_` or`\int_` are highlighted like token lists or sequences, but that can be accomplished by editing his lisp code (e.g. inserting `str\\` and `int\\` to the initial `specials` regex). Its at least a solution I could use and maybe adapt to my needs over time. But since it depends on emacs standard `latex-mode` (without caps), it doesn't offer the additional syntax highlighting features of AUCTeX. I'm sure that can be accomplished, but my emacs/lisp knowledge is too small at the moment to do so.

Beside that, it doesn't solve the auto complete question which would be even more helpful for programming purposes. Espacially concerning `NewDocumentCommand` and its siblings. Thus, I'm interested in more experience reports/own solutions etc.

Comment: I haven't seen a syntax highlighting for l3 code. Maybe ask here: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/auctex

Comment: @KeksDose. Sourcing the `expl3.el` file in AUCTeX's `style/` directory indeed offers kind of "highlighting" (it adds `_` and `:` as recognisable macro characters). But the highlighting is very unremarkable. Plus, the missing auto-completion is much more annoying while programming. Writing to the mailing list may be an option for later. But here, in the first way, I'm interested in the workflow/use-cases of experienced Latex developers/authors who are using Emacs and might be also aware of this shortcoming, as well as their practical solutions/ways dealing with it.

Comment: Emacs is mentionned at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129439/86

Comment: @AndrewStacey thanks. Thats one of the post (if not the only improtant one) on TeX.SE which offers some useful informations. Its linked from the post I mentioned in my question. Of course, I tested your own `latex3-mode` and it works quite well with syntax highlighting, not to say, it might be the best working l3 highlighting I've found so far. I've edited my question to make that a little bit clearer.

Comment: I once made the suggestion to move the xparse style file to `latex.el`, the answer was "that's the plan", but it's not ready yet (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex-devel/2021-08/msg00021.html). Personally, in the meantime, I just run `(TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse")` at `LaTeX-mode-hook`. I do get proper syntax highlighting for `expl3` commands with a current AUCTeX (not dim gray as you report), in both .tex and .dtx files. Regarding completion of commands, I'd say this is probably indeed lacking. I'm not even sure `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends automatically add the symbol ...

Comment: ... as `\newcommand` does. Not to mention the many ways to create new macros with `expl3`. But this is a huge task. I'm sure developers are aware, and it's fair to consider it a "work in progress". And, most likely, an offer of a helping hand would be welcome at the list. Also, you always have local and site style files which you can populate with commands, so you do have the infrastructure to do it for your commands which are not automatically parsed.

Comment: Correction, `xparse.el` does take care that commands created with `\NewDocumentCommand` and friends are automatically added to completion, as for `\newcommand` and frients.

Comment: @gusbrs thanks for your detailed comments. The `TeX-run-style-hook` is a great hint and maybe the answer to my question on [emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/79111/41665). But how do you get a proper syntax highlighting by default? I run AUCTeX 13.2 which should be the current version and always need to parse `expl3` for the dim gray version which is much inferior to Andrew Stacey's own definition.

Comment: @lukeflo I'll add an answer that question later. But, regarding syntax highlighting, I don't add infrastructure, but I might be making some setup I forgot about. However, I'm pretty sure this is supported out of the box. `font-latex.el` has a variable for valid macro characters `font-latex-match-simple-include-list` which, by default includes only `@` but `expl3.el` modifies it to add `_` and `:`. So, as far as I can tell, this should be out of the box, as long as the `expl3.el` style file gets loaded (which happens if `xparse.el` is loaded).

Comment: @lukeflo See https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/font-latex.el#n1754 and https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style/expl3.el#n55.

Comment: @gusbrs - For the sake of completeness: There is also one other restriction reg. fontification of macros like `\__foo`.  This works only in `docTeX`-mode.  See the definition of the function `font-latex-match-simple-command `.

Comment: Hi @ArashEsbati! Yes, I'm aware of it, and I wonder why restrict this to `docTeX-mode` only. Also, I'm currently circumventing this with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697954/looking-for-a-good-emacs-auctex-setup-for-latex3?noredirect=1#comment1734794_698189. Trying it out for the time being. Btw, this discussion (and the related one at Emacs.SX) made me wonder if moving `xparse` to `latex.el` even if incomplete wouldn't be better. The OP really did their job in trying to understand things, and came up with an arguably frustrating situation. WDYT?

Comment: @gusbrs - This is a compromise in order to have `\_` in regular .tex files fontified correctly (i.e., no fontification like some other control symbols).  Check [this file](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/tests/latex/fontification-general.tex) for some explanations.  Reg. your solution: I think the cleanest solution is if people using these macros send patches against [`ltx-base.el`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/style/ltx-base.el). Reg. `xparse.el`: Yes, it should be moved into `latex.el`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati Reg. `xparse.el`: Great to hear that from you, and looking forward to it. Thank you! Reg. patches, sorry I personally can't, no papers (I told you that before, but I don't presume you remember). Reg. `\_`, I do understand why its done, but the way it is currently done seems like a crude workaround. It shouldn't be difficult to generalize and distinguish the situation in the matcher function. E.g. by the length of the match ("1 char" vs "longer"), by the fact that internal `expl3` functions start with two `\__`, whatnot. With `exp3` gaining more importance, it's probably worth it.

Comment: @ArashEsbati As far as I can tell, the case at `font-latex-match-simple-command` could be easily handled by making that anonymous group a numbered one, and then testing if the length of its match is larger than 0. ;-)  (Given that the case `font-latex-match-simple-exclude-list` is trying to capture is that of single character macros).

Answer (score 5):

I have looked (admittedly, not very hard), and like you, didn't find much. As a result, I currently use a self-written (in elisp) `LaTeX3-mode`, which is an extension of the basic `latex-mode` (not AucTeX) when dealing with LaTeX3 style and class files. Most of my code is syntax highlighting, with almost everything else (key-combos, autocomplete, indenting, etc) inherited from the `LaTeX-mode` which comes with emacs (`tex-mode.el`). I'm not sure how well it will work with `.dtx` files (if at all), or if I'll need to write a module for those as well.

I do intend on publishing it "Real Soon Now" (so, eventually - probably late next year). If there is a high enough level of interest, my effort and attention may be increased, and it will be "early next year" rather than "probably next year, maybe about September or so at the earliest". (Comments indicating interest gratefully received, as are suggestions of how and where to publish and announce the publication for best effect.)

I am also interested in other people's solutions, mostly so I know if I should keep working on mine, or use theirs and abandon my attempts.

---

Edit to add:

The mode I am working on is similar to (but not based on) @AndrewStacy's mode, which is linked to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129439/latex3-sensitive-editors). At least, not directly based on. I am fairly sure that I saw Andrew's mode before I coded mine, but didn't directly copy anything.

---

Further edit, in case the comments are culled at any point: This has now been published at [github](https://github.com/enkorvaks/emacslatex).

Comment: That sounds very interesting and I would like to try it out as soon as you've published it. But if I got it right, you're not using/deriving commands etc. from AUCTeX. I would like to keep all advantages of AUCTeX with a really good working latex3 mode like yours or the one Andrew Stacey provided.

Comment: From comments (on the question and other answer) and upvotes, it appears that there is a bit of interest here. I will look more seriously at getting my code available to the public for use and comment.

Comment: @enkorvaks If I may suggest, why don't you consider contributing improved support for LaTeX3 to AUCTeX itself? (It may or may not be your cup of tea, and all is welcome either way ;-).

Comment: @gusbrs, I was intending on getting AUCTeX soon, to at least look at. I had a quick peek last night, but the dependencies (from the package manager) look like they want to download all of `TeX common`.  I currently use a manually installed TeX-Live, and haven't done package equiv workaround, so it may be a few days before I can check it out. I will see what time the weekend allows me...

Comment: @enkorvaks You can always just install it from Emacs itself `package.el`. Or, if you're aiming at the built-in `tex-mode` you could also consider contributing to Emacs. Whatever you come up with, I'm also looking forward to it. :-)

Comment: @gusbrs (also lukeflo, but I can only at-tag one person, and as questioner, you should be notified). My initial draft is now published (or at least, is publically accessible) on GitHub: https://github.com/enkorvaks/emacslatex . Comments and suggestions welcome.

Comment: @lukeflo ^^^^ (pinging you too).

Comment: @enkorvaks Thank you! It looks good. Indeed, it seems like the basic structure of Andrew Stacey's one, but with (a lot) more polish. At first sight, I think it would be more "colorful" than my own personal taste. But I do see the appeal in highlighting all of those categories, and probably a number of people will like it (presumably lukeflo among them ;-).

Comment: @enkorvaks thanks for the info. I'll take a look ASAP. But that probably will only be tomorrow or Monday.

Comment: @enkorvaks Some comments/questions. You might want to add `@` to `re-string-l3-chars` to include the use of `@@` for docstrip replacements. Why do you need those `(backward-char)` in your search functions? (I don't understand, and it looks weird).

Comment: @gusbrs the `(backward-char)` is there because of the regular expressions: without it, only the first of `\thing\otherthing` would be highlighted, and this produces odd highlighting: `\@privatething\thing\secondthing` - `\secondthing` shows up as L2-private, instead of L2-public. Not all combinations seem to have the problem, but I put the `(backward-char)` in all of them (even if it doesn't appear needed everywhere), and the highlight problems seem to go away. The `@` has been added to `re-string-l3-chars` now.

Comment: @enkorvaks Mhm, I think I understand what you are trying to do. As far as I get, you need to go back because of `re-string-end-macro`, but I'd say you are being over-zealous there. If you just add (all) valid macro characters (catcode 11) to your other regexps the match will naturally end where it should. If you really feel you need something there, you can go with the end of symbol regexp (`\_>`). Well, just a suggestion, of course. ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs That's probably a fair comment - I learnt emacs-lisp by reading code and trying things. As a result, the code you see is what I could get to work. Yes, `re-string-end-macro` could probably do with more characters, or something else similar. If it was a PCRE, I would have used a zero-width (negative?) look-ahead, but emacs-lisp doesn't have one, so I faked it with a `(backward-char)` (probably suggested on an emacs.se search) at the end. If you have better code suggestions, please clone-branch-edit-push my repo, and raise a PR. Unless I need different settings on github to allow that.

Comment: @enkorvaks Me too, learning by trying.  ;-) And, of course, what works has something for it. Cheers!

Comment: @enkorvaks Just tested your `latex3` setup. Really looks great. The possibility to have slightly different colours for private and public macros makes sense when working on `dtx`, `sty` or `cls` files. Is there a reason you derive it from standard `latex-mode`? Its the same for me learning emacs-lisp by trying and right now most of all copying and editing. But I'm still at the very start of everything regarding emacs.

Comment: @lukeflo I derived from the standard `latex-mode` rather than `auctex` largely because I haven't used Auctex much (not at all until earlier this week). The way I work (which I realise isn't for everyone) is that I don't tend to use automating features. Mostly, I just use the syntax-highlight, and ignore most of the other things the mode can do (except compile). Since I have looked more at Auctex, I will be updating my code to change the face-names to more closely match the Auctex naming, so it may be more compatible. I may see if deriving from Auctex works, and may make that an option.

Comment: @enkorvaks You also have a point with the simpleness. Sometimes the plain approaches are much less distracting. One can get overwhelmed by additional features, at least for me this is sometimes the case. Nevertheless, the automatisation offered by AUCTeX are really helpful to me. Would be interesting to see your AUCTeX solution.

Comment: @lukeflo Having now downloaded AUCTeX, it appears that my style mode will work with that as well. Assuming the same username, it looks like you are watching my github project, so you may already know, but I have added a few (mostly document) files. Feel free to look, and add notes to the TODO file, if there are features you would like to request. It's a spare-time project, though, so I make no promises on time to implement.

Comment: @gusbrs Also letting you know, my mode works with AUCTeX if present, so feel free to grab the latest, and have a look (not much has actually changed, so far though - it's largely spare-time only)

Comment: @enkorvaks Great to hear that. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The many comments and hints so far have shown me different approaches to adapt a LaTeX setup which is a good workaround.

I provide it as kind of a partial answer to show some possible solutions and maybe invoke some more comments/advices. I will not accept it as answer to my own question as long as there are some unresolved issues and update it with new insights. Of course, other answers are still very welcome. Since there seems to be no final native solution up to this point, maybe we can collect different approaches/hacks here.

At the moment, I'm using the following (very reduced) setup in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(font-latex-sedate-face ((t (:foreground "dark orange"))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "dim gray")))))

;;LaTeX;;

(setq TeX-parse-self t) ; Enable parse on load.
(setq TeX-auto-save t) ; Enable parse on save.

;; parse xparse by default
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my/LaTeX-mode-setup)
(add-hook 'docTeX-mode-hook 'my/LaTeX-mode-setup)
(defun my/LaTeX-mode-setup ()
  (TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse")
  (visual-line-mode)
  (electric-pair-local-mode))
```

The most important part regarding `latex3` syntax is the automatic parsing of `xparse.el` with `(TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse")`. It solves two issues partially:

1. Xparse macros like `\NewDocumentCommand` etc. are now accessable through `TeX-insert-macro` mechanism, including suggested insertion of argument specifiers etc, and highlighted properly.
2. At least, `xparse.el` parses `expl3.el` itself which results in `latex3` commands being recognized as cohesive command-name. The highlighting of these commands can be altered setting `(font-latex-sedate-face ((t (:foreground "dark orange")))` (here in orange).

Both aspects together are really supporting programming in `latex3`. *Unfortunately*, `latex3` commands like e.g. `\seq_new:N` are still totally missing from auto-completion/macro insertion!

As the answers resp. comments of @gusbrs and @enkorvaks imply, such an adaption might be not so easy to implement properly. My own `lisp` knowledge is too small to evaluate this issue.

Regarding better syntax highlighting the solution by @AndrewStacey is also very interesting. His syntax highlighting of `latex3` is definitly superior to the simple solution provided by `expl3.el`. It would be great to adapt this code to the `LaTeX-mode-hook` of AUCTeX. Maybe I (or someone else) will be able to realise that in the future. Moreover, I'm anxious to have a look at enkorvaks own solution.

Up to this point, there can some things be done/adapted but others are still up to be solved.

At least in my case, the mentioned adaptions are satisfying enough to finally switch from VSCode/vscodium to emacs. I'm still very new to the latter but the speed to manage programming tasks (esp. in LaTeX) with all those key-shortcuts totally convinced me. Thus, the flaws in `latex3` recognition do not weigh that heavily.

---

**Edit**

Thanks again to @gusbrs for providing his [workaround](https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/730758305ae701c915eb928f8c803328) for `latex3` syntax highlighting using AUCTeX. I took it and added some new `font-lock` faces which are reserved for highlighting `latex3` commands to avoid confusion with `latex2e` commands. So far, it works great and I hope others can use it as well. If someone detects a inconsistency or similar, I'm happy to hear it.

Here the adapted code in my `.emacs.d/init.el` (just added below the snippet posted above):

```lisp
;; try own face setup ; https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/53023/41665
(defface flo-font-lock-latex3-variable-face `((t (:foreground "chocolate")))  "Chocolate highlight")
(defvar flo-font-lock-latex3-variable-face 'flo-font-lock-latex3-variable-face
  "Variable for face flo-font-lock-latex3-variable-face.")
(defface flo-font-lock-latex3-keyword-face `((t (:foreground "orchid"))) "Orchid highlight")
(defvar flo-font-lock-latex3-keyword-face 'flo-font-lock-latex3-keyword-face
  "Variable for face flo-font-lock-latex3-keyword-face.")
(defface flo-font-lock-latex3-type-face `((t (:foreground "dark orchid"))) "Dark Orchid highlight")
(defvar flo-font-lock-latex3-type-face 'flo-font-lock-latex3-type-face
  "Variable for face flo-font-lock-latex3-type-face.")

;; latex3 highlighting, adapted from https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/730758305ae701c915eb928f8c803328
(with-eval-after-load 'font-latex
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flo/LaTeX-expl3-font-lock-setup)
  (add-hook 'docTeX-mode-hook 'flo/LaTeX-expl3-font-lock-setup)
  (defun flo/LaTeX-expl3-font-lock-setup ()
    (let ((signatures "NncVvoxefTFpwD")
          (vartypes '("clist" "dim" "fp" "int" "muskip" "seq" "skip"
                      "str" "tl" "bool" "box" "coffin" "flag" "fparray"
                      "intarray" "ior" "iow" "prop" "regex")))
      (font-lock-add-keywords
       nil
       `((,(concat "\\(\\\\\\(?:@@_\\|\\(?:__\\)?[a-zA-Z]+_\\)[a-zA-Z_]+\\)"
                   "\\(:[" signatures "]*\\)")
          .
          ((1 'flo-font-lock-latex3-keyword-face)
           (2 'flo-font-lock-latex3-type-face)))
         (,(concat "\\(\\\\[lgc]_[a-zA-Z@_]+"
                   "_\\(?:" (mapconcat #'identity vartypes "\\|") "\\)\\_>"
                   "\\)")
          1 'flo-font-lock-latex3-variable-face))))))
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! +1

Comment: Note though that you can add any given macro you wish to completion using style files, this is just not done for you automatically. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Also, it should not be too complicated to adapt Andrew Stacey's answer without the need of a specialized `latex3-mode`. As far as I can tell, all you need is to feed the same keywords to `(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode ....)`.

Comment: For fun, this should work: `(let* ((specials "\\(bool\\|char\\|clist\\|cs\\|exp\\|file\\|group\\|keys\\|prop\\|q\\|seq\\|tl\\)_[a-zA-Z_:]+") (general "\\([a-zA-Z_@:]+\\)") (camel "\\([a-zA-Z@]+\\)") (nocamel "\\(?:[^a-zA-Z@_:]\\)") (slash "\\\\") (keywords (list (list (concat "\\(" slash specials "\\)") 1 'font-lock-function-name-face) (list (concat "\\(" slash camel "\\)" nocamel) 1 'font-lock-function-name-face) (list (concat "\\(" slash general "\\)") 1 'font-lock-variable-name-face)))) (font-lock-add-keywords nil keywords))`. Put it in your `my/LaTeX-mode-setup`.

Comment: What would be really nice though would be a variant of `font-latex-match-command-with-arguments` specialized in `expl3` so that it could infer some structure from functions' signatures. :-)

Comment: Ah, in the snippet above, note that I added `@` to `general`, so that it also captures docstrip replacement of `@@` in `doctex-mode` for variables.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response @gusbrs. I will try it out when I come back home in the evening.

Comment: I did something a little different than Andrew Stacey, see https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/730758305ae701c915eb928f8c803328. I'm not sure I like it yet, but it looks good at first sight, and I'll experiment with this for some time. Feel free to include it in the answer if you happen to like it.

Comment: I will try it and report ;)

Comment: Works great! Have edited it slight a little bit to add special highlighting *only* for `latex3` commands. See edit.

Comment: Good to hear. :-) And, I don't see the need to distinguish much from `latex2e` macros, specially since the names are quite conspicuous. But, of course, choose whatever faces you like.

Comment: While scrolling through my packages/classes, which can have hundreds of code lines, I like to recognise the latex3 parts directly by their colour without reading the macro names. But that is purely personal preference, of course.

Comment: @lukeflo, I have mine set to show L3 kernel, L3 private and L3 public in different colours, with L2 public and L2 private methods in different colours again. So it is possible to see at a glance which it is.  Of course, being emacs, you can set all the colours the same, if that's your preference. Mine is also set up that only class and style files (by default) are coded for latex3, so documents (`.tex` files) show up as standard `LaTeX-mode`

Comment: @enkorvaks the division between private, public and kernel commands for l3 as well as l2 also sounds very interesting and would expand my approach of just distinguishing between l3 and l2 in general. Furthermore, it would be interesting how you implemented the division (by recognising command names containing `__` for l3 and `@` for l2 I could imagine). I load l3 syntax also for my regular `.tex` documents. Even if it is not needed much there, it don't disturbs the regular code. And sometimes its helpful, e.g. in test documents evaluating questions from tex.de.

Comment: @lukeflo I'm still thinking here about the completion part. And I was wondering, you say you are coming from VSCode and trying to get the same stuff working in AUCTeX, but... does VSCode actually have support for `expl3` macros? How does it work? Is it like Emacs' completion at point? Or something more advanced as `TeX-insert-macro` (aka `C-c RET`)? Because, if it is only the former, you actually can get pretty good (not perfect...) results with `dabbrev`, and `dabbrev` can be plugged in the main completion at point packages, such as `corfu` and `company`. Did you try that?

Comment: @gusbrs vsvode has full support for `latex3` macros. But only, as far as I've tried, as TAB-completion at cursor. I'm not sure how its implemented in detail but it uses Microsoft's Intellisense auto completion system which I'm not familiar with. In the backend vscode relies on Electron and node.js. two further things I've not worked with. Nevertheless, I'll have a look. At best, it would be the advanced completion via `TeX-insert-macro`, but completion at point would also be better than nothing. Thus, I'll also look at `dabbrev` and hope to expand my Emacs knowledge reg. such things ;)

Comment: @lukeflo I see. I don't know how Intellisense generates candidates, but as you may know, `dabbrev` does so from the content of open buffers (configurable). And, if it is just TAB-completion at cursor, you should be able to get a similar experience. Anyway, I got dabbrev working using `cape`, by adding `(add-hook 'completion-at-point-functions 'cape-dabbrev 20 t)` to my `docTeX-mode-hook`. I use `corfu`, but the same should do for `company`. You can also use `dabbrev-completion` out of the box. Check it out.

Comment: @lukeflo Arash just announced `xparse` support has made to the latest release (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703376/105447), you may want to update your answer (and your setup).