# How can I improve the coloring of macrocode envronments?

Tags: expl3

In my opinion l3 layer code readability in `macrocode` environments, using the `doc/docstrip` system can be improved by adding a bit of color to the macros. I wrote some code to do this and an example of the output is sown in the image. I also did two more changes. The macro names are not printed in the margin, but inline ont top of the definitions. Any variants are printed in square brackets at the end of the line `[variants]`. Also at the end of the code block, it is redundant to say "End Definition of name1, name2" etc., as is obvious from the codeblock heading. If they have been documented, a link can be provided here. Although even this can be redundant if the list of macros in the heading can be made clickable.

Coloring is based on module prefixes. The intention is to provide contrast to enhance readability. LaTeX/TeX code is only partially colorized. i color only macros used as constructors, such as `\newcommand`.

my question is what other improvements can I make to this concept? How much of the code shold be colorized? Any other thoughts and suggestions welcomed.

[image: example with colored code]

Comment: I think I'd color the `:Nx` parts, to match, leaving them black makes them look like a separate token.

Comment: Possibly of interest: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/697954/105447

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did try this and to be honest I did not like it, easy to change though. IMHO is like painting a wall and the door the same color. I can make it an option though. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Any thoughts of getting the macro names out of the margin? With l3 names are too long I thought this allows the margins to be smaller, no need to wrap names in the margin either.

Comment: I can see the argument for, but a hard thing for people used to classic tex syntax to master is that `_` and `:` are letters, the coloring highlights `_` is part of the name but strongly hints `:` is not.

Comment: yes the margin layout often doesn't work well with long names

Comment: @gusbrs This is the output from latexing the code, not the editor. I think your link is for configuring the editor.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the question then.  ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Point taken, David, I changed the regex to capture them as well. For whatever reason, trying to edit and post a second image, does not allow me.

Comment: Why are backslashes black? That makes them look less like part of the thing which follows and isn't the way I've seen l2/TeX code coloured (but I'm hardly experienced). Personally, I don't like having to scan the line to find the variants. And I'm confused by the example. Something starting `\l__` should be an internal, local variable, but it seems to be a control sequence judging by the `:nN`. You should use braces for an `N` type argument: it should be a single token, but you have `{<tlvar>}`. To me a macro name is something like `\macro`, but `n` expects a (braced) list of tokens.

Comment: ``\tl_put_left:Nn ⟨tl var⟩ {⟨tokens⟩}`

Comment: @cfr The heading line is showing arguments rather than drop them in a syntax box, is like, \tl_put_left:Nn ⟨tl var⟩ {⟨tokens⟩}. It is is same style like the l3 manuals eg.  `\tl_put_left:Nn ⟨tl var⟩ {⟨tokens⟩}`, unless the l3 manuals should also be written as  \tl_put_left:Nn ⟨\tl var⟩ {⟨tokens⟩} which is better and less confusing!

Comment: `interface3.pdf` uses `<token>` for an `N` type argument. It does not brace it. I don't understand what you mean about the heading line. `\tl_put_left:Nn` is a control sequence. `\l__codedoc_get_hyper_target:nN` is **not** properly named. `\l__` indicates a variable, but `:nN` indicates a function. `\l__...:nN` is not anything in `expl3` syntax.

Comment: @cfr  Thanks. I get what you mean, my bad, I should have written \meta{...} \Arg{...}. As to the  \   to be colored or not. I originally had it like that and changed it, as the code started looking IMHO, as a wall of color.Your comment is similar to that made by David for the specifier part. My intention is to make the code more readable and less confusing, so point taken. I will change it.

Comment: @cfr My primary objective with the code was to colorize it, as many of us grow older readability is important. Second use one environment to replace `macro`, `function` and `variable`.  Third avoid too much white space.Random example from `interface.pdf`  `\seq_set_from_clist:NN ⟨sequence⟩ ⟨comma-list⟩`  has 8 lines in the l3 manual. Same meaning can be conveyed in one line. Fourth, if following this convention the description part of the doc, can be hyperlinked to the code easier and vice versa. So far the colorizer works both in the traditional sense or as I described it.

Comment: Your goal is laudable and judicious use of colour would be welcome, but I'm curious why you want to reduce white space. In general, I find that makes `interface3.pdf` rather easier to read. Of course, if people were going to print the thing, it'd be different, but I'm guessing few people do that. It would be nice to have the following text beside the 8 lines, I think, but I don't think compressing the information in those 8 lines into 1 would make it clearer. Rather the opposite. There are 4 different control sequences in that list. A single line would obscure that.

Comment: But part of it is personal, to be sure. My eyes do not work together and my brain does not combine the images from the two eyes. Scanning horizontally is harder work and more error prone than a list. And I'm much more likely not to find the correct next line. That's with ordinary text. Code provides fewer cues I've made a mistake. And colours are not unproblematic. You need to consider whether the contrasts which work for you will work for people with different kinds of colour blindness, for example. (But possibly you've thought of this as I notice you're not using red in addition to green.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149123/discussion-between-yiannis-lazarides-and-cfr).