# Loading xparse explicitly required for syntax coloring in emacs?

Tags: auctex, syntax-highlighting

I was surprised to discover that it is necessary to put `\usepackage{xparse}` in the preamble in order for syntax coloring to work for LaTeX3 macros in emacs -- or a package that loads `xparse` such as `fontspec`. Without `\usepackage{xparse}` emacs looks like this:
[image: no xparse]Non-LaTeX3 macros are colored as expected.

With `\usepackage{xparse}` emacs looks like this:
[image: with xparse]

On this site it is commonly suggested that it is unnecessary explicitly to load `xparse` as much of it is built into a current LaTeX build. And yet, syntax coloring for LaTeX3 does require it. I suppose this might be an AUCTeX issue, but I've not found anything about a requirement to load `xparse` and AUCTeX specifically.

Comment: NewDocumentCommand required xparse until the 2021 latex release, so this is simply an auctex issue needing update so it associates those commands with the built in latex format.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - This AUCTeX issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DavidCarlisle mentioned its an Emacs/AUCTeX thing. But you can automatise parsing of packages from your praeambel and always load `xparse` by adding the following to your `init.el`:

```
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my/LaTeX-mode-setup)
(defun my/LaTeX-mode-setup ()
  (TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse"))
```

Generally, `latex3` highlighting is not yet supported by AUCTeX. But take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698189/297560) for some good working hacks.

Comment: I supplied a missing close parenthesis and altered your code to: `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '((TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse")))` did not work. But you caused me to ask the right question and found this which worked: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79111/add-parsing-of-latex-style-el-file-to-latex-hook-using-auctex

Comment: There were too many parentheses due to a copy-paste error. I just inserted the solution from my question you linked.

Answer (score 2):

Support for *Document Command Parser*  (aka `xparse`) is now part of `latex.el` within AUCTeX and is available from ELPA with release 13.2.3 (2023-12-07).  Completion, fontification etc. are available OOTB with this release and there is no need to load `xparse.el` (which is now more or less no-op, besides providing the package options).

Comment: Ah, great news! Thank you very much!

Comment: @gusbrs - You're welcome.  Enjoy.  And please report back if things are not working as advertised.

Comment: I'm quite sure there'll be no need, but if I do find something, you know I will. Btw, curiosity, you said "Document Command Parser", what about `expl3` which used to be loaded by `xparse.el`, is it also supported (at least fontified) out of the box?

Comment: @gusbrs - AUCTeX has a style file `expl3.el` which caters for fontification, at least to some degree and inside `docTeX`-mode (IIRC).

Comment: I know, I'll have to adjust for this here then. Pretty much any document of mine has at least some `expl3`, and (for me at least) loading `expl3.el` by default is good thing and does not harm anyway. Thanks again!